# i need to chnge the button from login to add to cart when user login immediately

Tags: reactjs

how can i change the state of login to add to cart when the user login in first the header nav item will be login if the user login then i want the button to change to add to cart in React

i have used session.getitem() to check the whether their is data or not in component did mount and in component did update i have updated the state but some how the component did mount will not call

```
    import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { UserData } from '../../PostData';
import { ClipLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        loading: false,
        redirect: false
    }
    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        if (this.state.email && this.state.email !== '') {
            try {
                UserData(this.state.username, this.state.email).then(result => {

                    this.setState({ loading: false })
                    if (result.length) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify(result));
                        this.setState({ redirect: true })
                    } else {
                        alert("please enter the write email and username");
                    }

                })
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        } else {
            console.log("black")
        }

    }
    onChangeHandle = (e) => {

        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to="/" />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '50%', zIndex: '111111' }}>
                    <ClipLoader
                        sizeUnit={"px"}
                        size={150}
                        color={'#123abc'}
                        loading={this.state.loading}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup
                            controlId="formBasicText"
                        // validationState={this.getValidationState()}
                        >
                            <ControlLabel>username</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Enter username"
                                name="username"
                                onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
                            />
                            <FormControl.Feedback />

                            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                                onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
                            />
                            <FormControl.Feedback />
                            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="login"></input>

                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Login;
```

and in header

```
    import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';


class Header extends React.Component {

    state = {
        login: false
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const data = sessionStorage.getItem("login");
        if (data) {
            this.setState({ login: !this.state.login })
        }

    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.login !== this.state.login) {
            this.setState({ login: true })
        }

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <NavLink to="/" >Home</NavLink>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                        <LinkContainer to="/shop">
                            <NavItem eventKey={1}>Shop</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        {this.state.login ?
                            <LinkContainer to="/addtocart">
                                <NavItem eventKey={1}>Add To cart</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            :
                            <LinkContainer to="/login">
                                <NavItem eventKey={1}>Login</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                        }

                        <LinkContainer to="/signip">
                            <NavItem eventKey={1}>Sigup</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>

                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}



export default Header;
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` right after `const data = sessionStorage.getItem("login");` in `componentDidMount` to see if you are actually getting something?

Comment: yes i have tried to console log it print null but only when manuall refresh it shows data